# How to return array of id's when saving records in sails.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, return, sails.js

The mobile app is sending the server an array of records to be saved to the database.  The server is to iterate through the array of records, save each one, build an arrary of newly created ids and then return the array of ids back to the app.

The following code is saving the records correctly, but due to the asynchronous nature of javascript, when the outer function returns the inner function has not completed yet and the array of ids is still empty.

How do I get this function to return the returnIDs array AFTER it has been filled?

```
    create: function(req, res) {
    var returnIDs = [];
    for(var i in req.body){
        Test_session.create(req.body[i], function test_SessionCreated(err, test_Session) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return res.json(err);
            }
            returnIDs.push(test_Session.id);
        });
    }
    return res.json({ "ids": returnIDs.toJSON}, 200);
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think use [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) is easier than promise. If you use async.js then do this.

```
create: function(req, res) {
    var returnIDs = [];
    async.each(req.body, function(item, callback) {
       Test_session.create(item, function(err, test_Session) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            callback(err);
          }
          else
            callback();
       });
    }, function(err){
       res.json(200, { "ids": returnIDs});
    });
}
```

Comment: Wayne, thanks for the quick reply.  I tried your code and it returned an empty array.  I'm new to JS so please bear with me here...  where is the returnIDs array updated in this example?

Comment: Okay, so I added the line "returnIDs.push(test_Session.id);" right before the callback at the end of the async call and IT WORKS!  Thanks again!

Comment: oop, I forget the `array.push()`